# stripe is not submitting after taken card details

Tags: javascript, php, html, stripe-payments

Im having an issue with stripe. i can take the card details with with no error. but after its supposed to submit the form to my action page but it doesn't.

here is my form code:

```
<form action="core/actions/process_order.php" method="POST" >
<input type="hidden" name="paymentsFormToken" value="852867224992427769129218776" />
<input type="hidden" name="orderTotal" value="39.96" >
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="pk_test_7B8n52X1er1vjx448Basdfasdfa"
data-amount="3996"
data-name="Test User"
data-currency="gbp"
data-description="Your order From Test.com">
</script>
</form>
```

I can't see anything wrong with this code, that might prevent it from submitting after taking card details. it just takes the card details then grays out the "pay with card" button!!!

Comment: If you try this: http://jsfiddle.net/oprq6khu/ you'll see it submit so there must be something else blocking you. Is there anything in the console for example? Are you sure it's not posting but then failing for some reasons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
the action page was wrong and it didnt exist, thats why the form didnt submit.

it the stripe checkout script will check if the action page exists or not before submitting.

Please accept my apology it was my mistake.

thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just make a submit input. Use the code below

```
<form action="core/actions/process_order.php" method="POST" >
<input type="hidden" name="paymentsFormToken" value="852867224992427769129218776" />
<input type="hidden" name="orderTotal" value="39.96" >
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="pk_test_7B8n52X1er1vjx448Basdfasdfa"
data-amount="3996"
data-name="Test User"
data-currency="gbp"
data-description="Your order From Test.com">
</script>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name"submit" />
</form>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: thanks but nope its the same thing, just takes out the card details , refresh, then grays out the "pay with car" button.